# How do I see if a value exists in any property for gremlin?

Tags: gremlin, graph-databases, tinkerpop3

I have a gremlin 3.4.9 set up, with a few different types of vertexes. (people, jobs, homes for example). I want to be able to traverse all of these samples and see if any of the properties contain a value.
for example:

I have a:

people vertex with the properties: name, age, location, bio

job vertex with the properties: title, pay, location, description

home vertex with the properties: cost, location, description

and I want to see if any of these properties of these vertices contain the value "family".
What would that query look like?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can search the properties values like this:

`g.V().properties().hasValue("family");`

This seems to work across different Vertices (which I believe is what you are looking for)

Comment: this doesn't throw an error like the one with the where clause, however, I am getting just an empty array, when I know at least one vertex contains the value.

Comment: nevermind, dumb typo!! this is exactly what I was looking for, thank you

Comment: can you confirm your vertex does not have an empty space or typo?

Answer (score 2):

You can accomplish this using a combination of the `properties()` step and the `hasValue()` step like below.  However, I would not expect this to be very performant on most/all databases as it will be unable to use any indexes or optimizations.

```
g.V().where(properties().hasValue("family"))
```

[Properties Step](http://tinkerpop.apache.org/docs/current/reference/#properties-step)

[Has Step](http://tinkerpop.apache.org/docs/current/reference/#has-step)

Comment: Thank you, but I get an error saying properties is not defined?

Comment: im using node and gremlin npm if that helps

Comment: You probably need to import the anonymous traversal __ (const __ = gremlin.process.statics;) and then add it in front of properties (__.properties())

Comment: I have the anonymous traversal imported, but its still being weird with contains

Comment: What do you mean by "being weird with contains"?

Comment: even after using the __ it says contains doesn't exist.

Comment: This code works for me: const gremlin = require('gremlin');
const traversal = gremlin.process.AnonymousTraversalSource.traversal;
const __ = gremlin.process.statics;
const DriverRemoteConnection = gremlin.driver.DriverRemoteConnection;

const g = traversal().withRemote(new DriverRemoteConnection('ws://localhost:8182/gremlin'));

g.V().where(__.properties().hasValue('family')).next()